Faust consumer/agent doesnt run on the first initialization
When I run my docker-compose for the first time and run my faust app for the first time after that, the producer sends messages ok but the consumer doesn't get the messages. If I restart the app, it works fine. My app looks like:
import random

import faust
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from time import time


class StockTransaction(faust.Record):
    date: datetime
    price: float
    stock: str


class Candlestick(faust.Record):
    start_aggregation_period_timestamp: datetime
    end_aggregation_period_timestamp: datetime
    start_price: float
    high_price: float
    low_price: float
    end_price: float
    aggregation_count: int

    def aggregate_transaction(self, stock_transaction: StockTransaction):
        unit_price = stock_transaction.price

        if self.aggregation_count == 0:
            self.start_aggregation_period_timestamp = stock_transaction.date
            self.end_aggregation_period_timestamp = stock_transaction.date
            self.start_price = unit_price
            self.low_price = unit_price
            self.end_price = unit_price

        if self.start_aggregation_period_timestamp > stock_transaction.date:
            self.start_aggregation_period_timestamp = stock_transaction.date
            self.start_price = unit_price

        if self.end_aggregation_period_timestamp < stock_transaction.date:
            self.end_aggregation_period_timestamp = stock_transaction.date
            self.end_price = unit_price

        self.high_price = max(self.high_price or unit_price, unit_price)
        self.low_price = min(self.low_price or unit_price, unit_price)
        self.aggregation_count += 1


TOPIC = 'raw-event'
SINK = 'agg-event'
TABLE = 'tumbling_table'
KAFKA = 'kafka://localhost:9092'
CLEANUP_INTERVAL = 1.0
WINDOW = 10
WINDOW_EXPIRES = 20
PARTITIONS = 1


app = faust.App(TABLE, broker=KAFKA, topic_partitions=1, version=1)
app.conf.table_cleanup_interval = CLEANUP_INTERVAL


source = app.topic(TOPIC, value_type=StockTransaction, key_type=str)
sink = app.topic(SINK, value_type=Candlestick)


def window_processor(stock, candlestick):
    print(candlestick)
    sink.send_soon(value=candlestick)


candlesticks = app.Table(
    TABLE,
    default=lambda: Candlestick(
        start_aggregation_period_timestamp=None,
        end_aggregation_period_timestamp=None,
        start_price=0.0,
        high_price=0.0,
        low_price=0.0,
        end_price=0.0,
        aggregation_count=0
    ),
    partitions=1,
    on_window_close=window_processor
).tumbling(
    timedelta(seconds=WINDOW),
    expires=timedelta(seconds=WINDOW_EXPIRES)
).relative_to_field(StockTransaction.date)


@app.timer(0.1)
async def produce():
    price = random.uniform(100, 200)
    await source.send(
        key="AAPL",
        value=StockTransaction(stock="AAPL", price=price, date=int(time()))
    )


@app.agent(source)
async def consume(transactions):
    transaction: StockTransaction
    async for transaction in transactions:
        candlestick_window = candlesticks[transaction.stock]
        current_window = candlestick_window.current()
        current_window.aggregate_transaction(transaction)
        candlesticks[transaction.stock] = current_window


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.main()

And the docker-compose looks like:
version: '3.6'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    restart: unless-stopped

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: 'order-books:3:2'
    restart: unless-stopped

  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:3.27.0
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 19000:9000
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:29092
    restart: unless-stopped

On the first initialization I get:
C:\Users\mclea\anaconda3\envs\faust-candlesticks\python.exe C:\Users\mclea\src\faust-candlesticks\app.py worker -l debug 
+ƒaµS† v0.11.2+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id          | tumbling_table                                               |
| transport   | [URL('kafka://localhost:9092')]                              |
| store       | memory:                                                      |
| web         | http://localhost:6066/                                       |
| log         | -stderr- (debug)                                             |
| pid         | 11664                                                        |
| hostname    | tommclean                                                    |
| platform    | CPython 3.11.9 (Windows AMD64)                               |
|        +    | Cython (MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64))                           |
| drivers     |                                                              |
|   transport | aiokafka=0.11.0                                              |
|   web       | aiohttp=3.10.5                                               |
| datadir     | C:\Users\mclea\src\faust-candlesticks\tumbling_table-data    |
| appdir      | C:\Users\mclea\src\faust-candlesticks\tumbling_table-data\v1 |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
Group Coordinator Request failed: [Error 15] GroupCoordinatorNotAvailableError
Topic raw-event is not available during auto-create initialization
Group Coordinator Request failed: [Error 15] GroupCoordinatorNotAvailableError
Topic raw-event is not available during auto-create initialization
Group Coordinator Request failed: [Error 15] GroupCoordinatorNotAvailableError
Topic raw-event is not available during auto-create initialization
Group Coordinator Request failed: [Error 15] GroupCoordinatorNotAvailableError
Topic raw-event is not available during auto-create initialization
Group Coordinator Request failed: [Error 15] GroupCoordinatorNotAvailableError
Topic raw-event is not available during auto-create initialization
 OK ^

And it sends messages fine to the raw-event topic, but the consumer doesn't read any messages. On the second time running the app, I get:
C:\Users\mclea\anaconda3\envs\faust-candlesticks\python.exe C:\Users\mclea\src\faust-candlesticks\app.py worker -l debug 
+ƒaµS† v0.11.2+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id          | tumbling_table                                               |
| transport   | [URL('kafka://localhost:9092')]                              |
| store       | memory:                                                      |
| web         | http://localhost:6066/                                       |
| log         | -stderr- (debug)                                             |
| pid         | 9728                                                         |
| hostname    | tommclean                                                    |
| platform    | CPython 3.11.9 (Windows AMD64)                               |
|        +    | Cython (MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64))                           |
| drivers     |                                                              |
|   transport | aiokafka=0.11.0                                              |
|   web       | aiohttp=3.10.5                                               |
| datadir     | C:\Users\mclea\src\faust-candlesticks\tumbling_table-data    |
| appdir      | C:\Users\mclea\src\faust-candlesticks\tumbling_table-data\v1 |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
 OK ^
<Candlestick: start_aggregation_period_timestamp=1724361217, end_aggregation_period_timestamp=1724361219, start_price=189.76106609658018, high_price=189.76106609658018, low_price=105.2808779884955, end_price=105.2808779884955, aggregation_count=24>
<Candlestick: start_aggregation_period_timestamp=1724361220, end_aggregation_period_timestamp=1724361229, start_price=187.37812934079548, high_price=199.99724165672342, low_price=100.35921078816915, end_price=193.91107473467878, aggregation_count=91>
...
Topic agg-event is not available during auto-create initialization
Topic agg-event is not available during auto-create initialization

So works fine. How can I fix this so that the app works successfully on the first launch?

Have you tried listing the topics in KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS rather than trying to have faust create them?

@OneCricketeer I did add that in the end and it did help, still takes quite a while to start but does start eventually. Was just hoping there was another way to do it! Is there a better way to create topics? What if you had hundreds or thousands of topics?

That's an architectural problem, IMO. It's generally not recommended to have topics be auto created within applications, especially when needing authentication and certificate generation in secure environments. Then you'd externalize topic creation to some CI/CD or IAC process

@OneCricketeer Do you know of any good existing CI/CD tools to do this?

If you use Kubernetes, then Strimzi and ArgoCD are a good option. Otherwise, terraform can create topics and kafka clusters.... Ultimately, it's up to you to write the scripts to programmatically manage the infrastructure, so the tool doesn't matter
